# left rotation operation for nested loop in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I would like to use nested loop to do the left rotation operation on an array.

parameter:
`a` -> array
`d` -> times of rotation

input example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
d = 4
```

expected output:

```
[5 1 2 3 4]
```

output for my code:

```
[2 3 4 5 1]
```

seems it only do the loop when `j = 0` (`i = 0` to `4`)

how to rewrite it to get the expected output?

```
function rotLeft(a, d) {
    // Write your code here
    var n = a.length
    var temp = 0
    var i = 0
    var j = 0
    for (j; j < d; j++) {
        for (i; i < n; i++) {
            if (i === 0) {
                temp = a[i];
            }
            a[i] = a[i + 1]
        }
        a[n - 1] = temp
    }

    return a
}
```

Comment: Do you want to return a new array, or the same array with updated indices?

Comment: just want to  return 'a' after d times of rotation

Comment: Wouldn't `array.unshift(array.pop())` do the trick without a loop?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove all the elements that are going to be shifted and then use another `Array#splice` to add them all at the end

```js
/**
 * @param {Array<string>} list
 * @param {number} rotationCount
 * @returns 
 */
function rotLeft(list, rotationCount) {
    rotationCount = (rotationCount % list.length) | 0; // ignore extra rotations and floor number
    if (rotationCount < 0) rotationCount += list.length; // convert right to negative left
    var removedParts = list.splice(0, rotationCount); // cut the first `rotationCount` elements
    list.splice.apply(list, [list.length, 0].concat(removedParts)); // add the removed elements to the bottom
    // list.splice(list.length, 0, ...removedParts); // or this for es6
    return list;
}

console.log(rotLeft([1,2,3,4,5], 4));
```